# What is the value of $I^2$ if $I=\int^{\pi/4}_{-\pi/4}\frac{\sqrt{\cos x}}{\left(\sqrt{\cos x}+\sqrt{\sin x}\right)^5}\,dx$?

Tags: definite-integrals

> If $$I=\int^{\pi/4}_{-\pi/4}\frac{\sqrt{\cos x}}{\left(\sqrt{\cos x}+\sqrt{\sin x}\right)^5}\,dx$$, then what is $27I^2$?

Plan:

$$I=\int^{\frac{\pi}{4}}_{-\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{\sec^2 x}{\left(1+\sqrt{\tan x}\right)^5}\,dx$$

Put $\tan x=t$ and $\sec^2 dx=dt$

$$I=\int^{1}_{-1}\frac{2t}{(1+t)^5}\,dt$$

How do i solve it help me

Comment: You have a bad singularity at $t=-1$.

Comment: Assuming that you are integrating this over the reals $\sqrt{\sin{(x)}}$ is undefined for $-\pi/4\le x\lt0$.

Comment: The integral doesn't make sense. What is $\sqrt{\sin(x)}$ when $x \in (-\frac{\pi}{4}, 0)$?

Comment: Algebra error: your transformed integral should be $\int_{-1}^1 2t/(1+\sqrt{t})^5dt$.

Comment: @eyeballfrog No it shouldn't. It would be $$\int_{-1}^1\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{(1+\sqrt{t})^5}$$

Comment: @PeterForeman Oh right. I forgot to check the numerator, too. Of course that still leaves the $t <0$ problem...

Comment: If you correct the bounds to $0$ and $\pi/4$ respectively we have that $$\int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{\sqrt{\cos{(x)}}}{(\sqrt{\cos{(x)}}+\sqrt{\sin{(x)}})^5}\mathrm{d}x=\frac{11}{96}$$

Comment: I got the final answer as
>$$\frac{4i+1}{6(i+1)^4}-\frac{5}{96}$$


Am i correct ?

Comment: There are two mistakes in this question (1) the domain of integration needs to be $(0,\pi)$ and $\tan x=t^2$, the the answer is $11/96$.

Answer (score 1):

Let me bother about the last step of yours: $$ I=\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{2t dt}{(1+t)^5}.$$
Sorry, this is Improper and divergent (infinite).

One way,  an Integral $\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx$ becomes Imporper if it diverges at either of the limits $x=a,b$ or in the domain $(a,b)$. Interestingly, if $ f(x) \sim (x-a)^{-k}$, $I$ could be convergent (finite) if $0< k <1$, otherwise it will diverge and become infinite. Look at the following example of Improper but convergent integrals.
$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{dx}{x^{0.99}}, \int_{0}^{1} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x}},~~ \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}.$$ Next, the following improper integral 
$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{dx}{x^{1.01}}, \int_{0}^{1} \frac{dx}{(1-x)^{3/2}},~~ \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{dx}{(1-x^2)^{3/2}}.$$ are diverget (infinite).
Also mind others comments.

In your original question if you make the the domain of integration as $[0,\pi/4]$, and write $\tan x= t^2$  your integral will be real and finite:
$$ J=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{2t dt}{(1+t)^5} = \int_{1}^{2} \frac{2(u-1)}{u^5 }du=\frac{11}{96}.$$